# When I run the following code, it gives me a NullPointerException – How do I fix it?

Tags: java

I have the following class called sendAttachment.java, and also Piechart.java, and covertExcelTOCSV.java. I am reading in an els file converting it to csv and then having piechart read the data make a pie chart save it and then send it into an email attachment. the bellow class sendAttachment.java is giving me a null pointer exception and i don't know how to fix it can someone help?

The error i get is this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:226)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:299)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1375)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1021)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:419)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1354)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2107)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2075)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:123)
    at de.vogella.jfreechart.swing.pie.sendAttachment.main(sendAttachment.java:61)
```

My code

```
package de.vogella.jfreechart.swing.pie;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class sendAttachment
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException
    {
        String host = "relay.apple.com";
        String from = "jsherif@apple.com";
        String to = "techjomana@gmail.com";

        // Get system properties
        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

        // Get session
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        // Define message
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Important Message From VMO");
        message.setText("Please see the attached Chart");

        // Handle attachment 1
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart1.attachFile("/Users/jomanasherif/Documents/mychart.jpg");

//        // Handle attachment 2
//        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
//        messageBodyPart2.attachFile("c:/Temp/b.txt");

        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
       // multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("message sent");

    }

}
```

Comment: Consider putting such question at codereview section

Comment: i have added the actual error above

Comment: @Desolator: [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) isn't the right place because they expect to post working code there. See their [faq](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq?mnu=1#dontask) for more info

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when the attached file cannot be read.

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
fileDataSource.getOutputStream().close();
```

after you have created and used `FileDataSource` object in your code. It should fix the problem (assuming fileDataSource is a FileDataSource object)

check out :
http://kenai.com/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.java?rev=469

also if you are sending attachments in the multipart message first try zipping them in your code and then send . You had encoding issues in this problem , these encoders are friendly with `.zip`s .

Answer (score 1):

The NullPointerException is being thrown in MimeUtility (line 226), rather than in the class you posted (though the problem likely originates in your code).

It looks like it has something to do with encoding. Without being able to delve into the code it's hard to know. Some things you could experiment with...

Try removing the parameter when you create the MimeMultipart:

```
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
```

Try attaching a different kind of file, e.g. a text file. Perhaps it can't detect the appropriate encoding for a "jpg" file.